# Можно ли обойти ограничения на количество запросов при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup, bs4

Пишу парсер для сбора данных с киногида. Данные записываю в json файл. Первые несколько запросов обрабатываются нормально, сохранюятся, как нужно, но потом вылетает ошибка о том, что слишком много запросов на домен.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import time
import random as rand


book_links_list = []
for page in range(0,87,1):
    url = f'https://knigogid.ru/books/page-{page}'
    q = requests.get(url)
    result = q.content # собираем ссылки на страницы с книгами

    soup = BeautifulSoup(result,'lxml')

    book_hrefs = soup.find_all(class_='b-item-name')

    for href in book_hrefs:
        book_links ='https://knigogid.ru'+href.get('href')
        book_links_list.append(book_links) #получаем ссылки на книги из блока с заголовком

with open('book_links_list', 'a') as file:
    for line in book_links_list:
        file.write(f'{line}\n') #записываем ссылки на книги в файл

data_dict = []
count = 0
with open('book_links_list') as file:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

    for line in lines:
        q = requests.get(line)
        result = q.content

        # while True:
        #     try:
        #         q = requests.get('https://www.kinogid.ru'+line)
        #         result = q.content
        #         break
        #     except:
        #         time.sleep(5)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')


        title = soup.find(class_='b-book-name').text
        series = soup.find(class_='b-book-series').text
        rate = soup.find(class_="b-item-rate").text
        views = soup.find('li').find('span').text
        author = soup.find(class_='b-book-user__name').text

        data = {
            'title':title,
            'author': author,
            'rate':rate,
            'views':views,
            'series':series
        }
        print(f'#{count}:{lines} is done!')
        data_dict.append(data)


        with open('data.json','w') as file:
            json.dump(data_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Подключать прокси не особо хочется, через Selenium результат тоже не лучше.
Можно ли собрать данные, если записать код страниц, которые собираюсь парсить, в текстовые документы и собрать нужные данные оттуда, чтобы не дудосить сайт?

Comment: на всякий случай, я имею ввиду можно ли собирать данные из текстового документа, а не открывть страницу сайта в браузере

Comment: book_links_list дублирование ссылок.

Comment: Первые несколько - это сколько? Я попробовал сайт помучать, без проблем забрал 200 страниц.

Comment: Желательно увидеть код и ошибку. По моим тестам можно бесконечно сайт опрашивать, даже без `headers`.

Comment: @DiMithras, в json-файл записывается данные по первым 5 ссылкам. дальше ошибка -   title = soup.find(class_='b-book-name').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @DiMithras а со сбором ссылок проблем нет. они нормально записываются

Comment: @СергейШ да, но при этом со сбором ссылок проблем нет. их собтрается просто в два раза больше, чем надо. Проблема в том, что у меня в какой-то момент перестают записываться данные в json-файл

Comment: @МатвейПрощенков как-то вы игнорируете вопрос. Через сколько страниц ошибка выходит?

Comment: @DiMithras, когда я написал вопрос, то через 5. сегодня запускал снова код и дошел до 11 страниц. потом снова та же ошибка. точнее будет сказать, что теперь ошибка была в следующей строке, но ошибка по своей сути таже самая

Comment: @DiMithras, написал проверку, после 5-ого запроса ловит капчу, и в json записывает null, с прокси тоже самое, страницы тоже скачать не получается по той же причине